# How to add a description to the user name input field in the registration form?

Tags: user-registration

I want a description **under the user name input field** in the Wordpress registration form like in the next example. How can I do this?

```
//create an extra field in login page for invitation code
add_action( 'register_form', 'add_invitation_code_field' );

function add_invitation_code_field() {
   ?>
      <p>
         <label for="invitation_code">
            Invitation code
            <input id="invitation_code" class="input" type="text" size="20" value="" name="invitation_code"/>
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Description text"); ?></span>
         </label>
      </p>
   <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, that's possible using JavaScript (jQuery lib). Code -

```
// load jquery on login screen if not loaded already
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_login_head' );
function wpse_login_head(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action( 'register_form', 'wpse_register_form' );
function wpse_register_form(){ ?>

    <!-- we have used an unique id for the description tag -->
    <span id="user_login_description" style=" display:none;" class="description"><?php _e("Description text"); ?></span>

    <!-- the following line of code move the description after the username input -->
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery('#user_login_description').appendTo('#registerform p:nth-child(1) label').show();</script>
   <?php
}
```

Comment: After changing the `function add_invitation_code_field(){ ?>` to `function awpse_register_form(){ ?>` this works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: In the same context, is there a way to change the style of the user name input field? I am trying to change the ``margin: 2px 6px 16px 0px;`` to ``margin: 2px 6px 6px 0px;`` but without succes :((.

Comment: Well this should be easy though. You can add CSS for `#user_login` selector, and use `login_enqueue_scripts` hook. I have written an article about [how to customize WordPress login screen](http://w4dev.com/wp/wordpress-login-page/) which have and example of login page CSS implementation.